# How to get the count or percentage of one factor variable in each decile ?

Tags: r, aggregate-functions, lapply

My dataset is like the following example

```
Tier Decile
1     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
2     1
2     2
1     2
3     2
3     2
3     2
1     3
2     3
2     3
3     3
3     3
```

I want to get the answer like the following if the simple count or may be in the percentage. 
Is lapply or Aggregate function can work ?

```
Tier    Decile1  Decile2  Decile3
Tier=  1    2        1       1
Tier = 2    2        1       2
Tier = 3    1        2       2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `table`. Assume `df` is your data.frame

```
> with(df, table(Tier, Decile))
    Decile
Tier 1 2 3
   1 2 1 1
   2 2 1 2
   3 1 3 2
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying ddply getting some errors, and your answer is so simple and working, Thanks @jilber